# Distance formula on a coordinate plane, does which set is $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ matter?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

If I have points $(a, b)$ and $(d, b)$ where $d<0$. When calculating the distance between the two points, does it matter whether it is $(a-d)$ or $(d-a)$ as long as I take the absolute value of the answer as the distance between the two points?

Comment: Given two points $A$ and $B$, $d(A,B)=d(B,A)$, so it doesn't matter which value are you taking first since you take absolute value.

Comment: The standard formula for the distance between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is $\sqrt{(x_1- x_2)^2+ (y_2- y_2)^2}$.  Since $(x_1- x_2)^2= (x_2- x_1)^2$ and $(y_1- y_2)^2= (y_2- y_1)^2$, no, the order does not matter.